# Adding list-styles to p tag

Tags: html, css

I know this seems silly, but I'm trying to add list-styles to p tags. I cannot put them in li tags because of how the php is looping. So I am kind of stuck trying to style them to look like a list.

I have tried something like this

```
.taskSubList{
  text-indent:2em;
  list-style-type:disc;
  display:list-item; 
}
```

but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Crc2x/)

Comment: It will help if you create a JSFiddle that replicates the problem.

Comment: Just posted a jsFiddle for you...and the html when it's outputted is just p tags with text inside it.

Comment: It works fine, if you add a `margin-left`: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Crc2x/1/).

Comment: I think the list style is applied though, its just not visible, you have to position the disc.

Comment: @DavidThomas if you post that as an answer I'll mark it! That was awesome, I didn't even think of adding a margin...that is such an odd html quirk!

Comment: I will say that this is not a duplicate of the linked question; since the OP here has already implemented the appropriate `display` property (the accepted answer to that question), it was simply a question of how to make the `list-style` marker *visible* (*not* how to implement/attach it to the `p` element).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this "didn't work" is because the default `list-style-position` is outside of the element(s) to which the `list-style-type` counter is applied; which means it's, by definition, outside of the left margin of the element. Therefore if you specify a `margin-left` (of a sufficiently-large number) it works perfectly:

```
p {
    text-indent:2em;
    list-style-type:disc;
    display:list-item;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Crc2x/1/).

Alternatively, if you specify `list-style-position: inside` it *also* works:

```
p {
    text-indent:2em;
    list-style-type:disc;
    display:list-item;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Crc2x/2/).

Comment: These don't quite work. First is best, but you should remove text-indent. It works without it and it also breaks the margin if the line wraps. The margin should also be 2.5em. http://jsfiddle.net/Crc2x/15/

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to accomplish that by using `list-style` on `p` tag as mentioned on other answers and comments.
But you also have another two choices here:

1. Use JavaScript to wrap p tags with `li` elements or more elegantly replace `p` tags with `ul` and `li` by means of JavaScript (jQuery) on load.
2. Use `background-image` to set disc image and give `padding-left` to `p` tag.

As `p` tag is not lists, it is semantically incorrect to use the solution with `list-style-type` and `display: list-item`. My Solution 2 is not semantically right either, as you still use `p` for list. If you have possibility to use Solution 1, it will be better, or simply modify PHP loop.

Comment: Did you even check the published [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Crc2x/)? It works fine, [if a `margin-left` is added](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Crc2x/1/).

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Crc2x/1/. It is possible

Comment: @DavidThomas jsfiddle was added after my answer. I will edit my answer to reflect the possibility.

Comment: But the CSS was already there; while the demo made it *easier* to experiment with, it didn't, really, add any new information.